# Site broken after modifying .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I recently added these lines to my .htaccess file on the server:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

What I was trying to do was eliminate the need for .php after the file name. This worked wonderfully, but something else was broken.

The URL for the website was `http://subdomain.something.domain/eCom/` and I had an index.php file in it, which was automatically loaded when the above link was used. But after editing the .htaccess file, the above link returns a 404 error. The page still opens correctly if I use `http://subdomain.something.domain/eCom/index` or `http://subdomain.something.domain/eCom/index.php`. I don't know what's happening. Anyway this can be resolved?

Note: I don't understand the code above about all the RewriteEngine stuff. I just copied from a website hoping for a quick fix. Any additional information about it is welcomed, if that's what's breaking my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` above your first `RewriteCond` to avoid matching directories as well.

Comment: Would you kindly explain what these lines do or mean? The site from where I accessed the info doesn't even explain these lines.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` says don't do any rewrites if the file exists. This will prevent files like `test.jpg` from trying to be rewritten (As `test.jpg` exists on your server). `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` says "If this directory exists, don't rewrite it".